# Sikuli Java find a select option that contains specific text

Tags: java, xpath, sikuli

I am trying to click on a specific option from a select statement using Sikuli in Java.

Given this select statement:

```
<select name="mySelect">
  <option value="ab">AB 273xc Some Text</option>
  <option value="cd">CD i8df4 Some More Text</option>
  <option value="ef">EF q43th And Text Once More</option>
</select>
```

The following works if I know the full exact text contained in the option:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='mySelect']/option[.='CD i8df4 Some More Text']")).click();
```

The problem is that there is always random text within the string (i8df4 in this case) which changes every time, so I will not know what this text will be.

So I want to click on the option that contains the text "Some More Text" at the end. I see there is a CONTAINS function but I cannot figure out how to use it in this case (if its even possible to use).

So need to do some kind of pattern match or regex in the option part like this:

```
option[.='do pattern match here looking for Some More Text']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the value of a part of text you can use `contains()`. Therefore you may try this:

```
"//select[@name='mySelect']/option[contains(.,'Some Text')]"
```

But in my view it would be better to use the value attribute:

```
"//select[@name='mySelect']/option[@value='ab']"
```

Comment: AWESOME! First answer is exactly what I needed! The part I could not figure out was putting the period in the CONTAINS as the first string which will compare to all option attributes found. 
And FYI the value attribute is randomly generated too (which I forgot to mention) so that would not have worked.